# Ways of inflating layout for RecyclerView's View Holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Currently, my RecyclerView adaptor is implementing two different view holders (One for main header, another for hidden child(s)). I got started to implement this type of arrangement from here: http://anandbose.github.io/android_recyclerview_expandablelistview.html

What I want to know is:
Prior to the mentioned post, I was inflating layout for the ViewHolder like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_maincategory_one,parent,false);
    return new ListHeaderViewHolder(view);
}
```

Which is a very basic way of doing so. In the mentioned post, the above was implemented something like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater headerInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = headerInflater.inflate(R.layout.include_expandable_recyclerview_header, parent, false);
            return new ListHeaderViewHolder(view);}
```

I want to know, what is the difference behind the two?
Because, the first method doesn't works the way I want to (And the way it's supposed to, in the mentioned post)

Short snippet of implementation (From post):

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    switch (viewType)
    {
        case CIRCLE_TITLE:
            LayoutInflater headerInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = headerInflater.inflate(R.layout.include_expandable_recyclerview_header, parent, false);
            return new ListHeaderViewHolder(view);

        case CIRCLE_ADMINS:
            LayoutInflater childInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = childInflater.inflate(R.layout.include_expandable_recyclerview_child,parent,false);
            return new ListChildViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: You are inflating two different layouts. Maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: And you only need one inflater, so no need to have individual ones in the switch case statements